# Restoring In-App Purchase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have added a non-consumable in-app purchase to my app to remove the ads. The purchasing works fine, its the restoring iam having trouble with. I just don't know what to do.

Here is my purchasing code:

```
    func buyNonConsumable(){
    println("About to fetch the products");
    // We check that we are allow to make the purchase.
    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
    {
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
        var productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID);
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        productsRequest.start();
        println("Fething Products");
    }else{
        println("can't make purchases");
    }
}

// Helper Methods
func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
    println("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
    var payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment);
}

func removeTheAds(){

    userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "proUser")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
    print("You are a pro User")

    //Code for removing the ads currently
}

// Delegate Methods for IAP
func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
    println("got the request from Apple")
    var count : Int = response.products.count
    if (count>0) {
        var validProducts = response.products
        var validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
            println(validProduct.localizedTitle)
            println(validProduct.localizedDescription)
            println(validProduct.price)
            buyProduct(validProduct);
        } else {
            println(validProduct.productIdentifier)
        }
    } else {
        println("no product found")
    }
}

func request(request: SKRequest!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("There was an error");
}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)    {
    println("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .Purchased:
                println("Product Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                removeTheAds()
                break;
            case .Failed:
                println("Purchased Failed");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;
                // case .Restored:
            default:
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

How do i handle restores? I have a restore button that calls both of these but what do i do now?

```
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

I see that case .Restored is commented out but i don't know what goes in there. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: There is a bug in your code: your default case is not calling `finishTransaction`. You must _always_ call `finishTransaction`!

Comment: Have edited my code. Could you check to see if i made the correct change?

Comment: Yes, that's all you needed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's up to you what you do when a payment is restored. What I do in my app is the same thing I do in the `.Purchased` case - I switch on the hidden functionality. It looks like in your app, you'd turn off the ads. In fact, in my app, `.Purchased` and `.Restored` are the same case, and you could probably do the same. This is a little of my code:

```
        switch t.transactionState {
        case .Purchased, .Restored:
            // ... turn on the magic ...
        }
```

Comment: So in my case restored i could just put my removeAds() (hides the ads) method? Also, am i right in calling both SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self) and
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions() in my restore button IBAction?

Comment: I think so. You don't need to add the same transaction observer multiple times, though. I like to use the app delegate as my observer and add it once, at launch.

Comment: Where abouts would i add an alert to show that there is no products to be restored? At the moment nothing happens when i press the restore button.

Comment: Ask that as a new question!