# Lack of restore function for in-app purchase causes rejection

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, restore

I hope this will not be ignored due to some answers that exist out there.  I did not see any Xcode answers.  I am a new developer in the app field and Xcode is what I have learned.  My question:

Are there any Xcode answers for solving the restore function problem in my app?

I have a non-consumable in-app purchase which is required by apple to provide a restore function.  I need the Xcode/Swift version.

Here is the purchase code in AppDelegate (notice it is Parse version):

import UIKit
import Parse
import Bolts

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    // Initialize Parse
    Parse.setApplicationId("supplied AppID from Parse", clientKey: "supplied Key from Parse")

    // Track statistics around application
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    PFPurchase.addObserverForProduct("REDI_REF_Mobil_Upgrade", block: { (transaction: SKPaymentTransaction!) -> Void in

        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "upgrade")

        userDefaults.synchronize()

    })

    return true
}
```

Now code from the main Upgrade button (purchase):

```
@IBAction func UpgradeButton(sender: UIButton) {

    PFPurchase.buyProduct("REDI_REF_Mobil_Upgrade", block: { (error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if error != nil {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    })

}
```

I would like to add the restore as a part of the 'Upgrade' button.

Comment: What do you mean by "Xcode answers"? All answers regarding iOS / Mac development can be considered "Xcode answers" since Xcode is what everybody has to use to actually build and submit their apps to Apple.

That said, I think this question is similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894194/restoring-in-app-purchase-swift

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am sorry that I was a little vague.  if you will see at the end of my original post I said Xcode/Swift.  Almost all of the other posts that I have looked at are in Objective-C.  My app is not written in Objective-C.  I was asking for the Xcode/Swift version.  It turns out your example is in Xcode/Swift.  I will check it out, thanks again.

Comment: In the interest of helping you fix your question, you will have better luck if you (for example) take an existing answer that is in Objective-C, note what part of it you're having trouble translating, and ask about that (posting complete with the suspect code and what you think you're running into). Simply asking for someone to do this for you -- especially when what "restore purchases" means is specific to your app's logic -- is effectively a fool's errand.

Comment: Brad,  I understand your point but I have effectively been told by Apple almost nothing other than the lack of a restore function.  I googled it and found a few similar requests (no code included in their question), and the responses are with Objective-C.  My not being familiar with Objective-C makes it hard to determine what I need and what I don't since each of these questions is not the same in-app purchase situation as mine.  I am not quite sure where to go from here.  I will try an provide some code.

Comment: Apple *won't* tell you what you need to do because the details will be specific to your app. When you "restore", will downloads be required? Will there be on/off flags set? Will there be server interaction? No one but you knows this.

Since the general approach is covered fairly clearly it seems appropriate to suggest you (re)read it. https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf

There's a whole section on "Restoring Previously Completed Purchases". At the very least, refer to specific sections there to help narrow your question/confusion.

Comment: Brad,  although you are trying to help you are stating the obvious.  I have 38 years experience creating programs from IBM card keypunch to mobile apps and everything in between.  I stated that Apple offered a lack of direction not to criticize but to set facts on where I am.  I have read the Apple docs multiple times.  You asked for coding snippets and I provided the complete Parse coding covering the original upgrade purchase.  Again, there are many answers to similar questions out there but almost none in Xcode/Swift.  I lack the experience to translate yet.  Thanks for help.

Comment: Perhaps I _am_ stating the obvious, and perhaps I'm just being dense (and argumentative to boot). However, somewhere along the way I missed that you're using Parse. I don't know how that changes things since I don't use it, but I can't imagine that negates the need to call restoreCompletedTransactions() in response to a UI element. The code you show doesn't call that. Is _this_ where you're getting stuck?

Comment: And as an aside, I doubt Apple will let you get away with hiding "Restore" under "Upgrade". I've seen a few different successful titles for the operation, but they all have the word "Restore" in them. (I am not Apple so never say never and all that, but based on experience...)

Comment: Brian,  I am the one who is dense.  I really appreciate your trying to help.  My button will actually be "Upgrade / Restore".  After the button is pushed, I have added an alert to determine which is desired.  Based upon the response I will execute either the purchase code which I am showing or the restore code which is where I am getting stuck.  Yes, you are correct.  Once that data is obtained I will set the NSUserDefaults variables on the new device and use these to allow the execution of the new functionality (upgrade).

Comment: The app contains the upgraded functionality from the beginning, but it is only accessible when the NSUserDefaults variable is 'true'.  I then allow the use of the functionality.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Here are two intentionally, pedantically specific questions: I mentioned the code `restoreCompletedTransactions()` (on `SKPaymentQueue` - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/); have you or have you not added this code to your app in response to the user selecting "Restore"? Why or why not?

Comment: Well, I pasted the wrong link for iOS, but the meaning is the same. Here is the corrected StoreKit doc link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/

Comment: Brad, I appreciate your trying to help me.  While you have been doing this I have continued to try and solve it myself.  It turns out that the answer I was looking for was buried deep in Parse.com documentation.  All I needed to add was one line.  "PFPurchase.restore()"  This line uses the existing Parse purchase code and observer block of code.  Problem solved, LOL, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you were looking for, but asking like this usually won't end up well here on SO in my experience. (You'd need at least some code, or google results, not just asking for code.)

You might want to have a look at: [Restore already bought in-app-purchases on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761556/restore-already-bought-in-app-purchases-on-iphone?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have already looked at this and many other stackoverflow answers to the problem of creating a restore function in an app containing IAP non-consumable purchases.  The problem with all of these existing answers is that they do not have the Xcode/Swift version of the restore coding.  That is what I am seeking.  I am not able to convert the existing answers on stackoverflow to Xcode/Swift.  One example is the item you listed.  Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe you can post a Objective-C version and your trial of port in Swift and let people see what we can help you to get it working.

Comment: Zhi-Wei,  I lack the experience in Objective-C to interpret and to know which parts of the answers I should include.